# Data analysis with only one independent binary variable in a time series

Tags: r, time-series, binary-data

I have a time series dataset of air pollution with with one discrete dependent variable: `nitrogen dioxide` and one binary explanatory variable: `congestion charge` (1=yes, 0=no).
The dataset contains several cities with several years.
Here is a small exemplary section of the data set (written in R):

```
library(tidyverse)

df<-tribble(
  ~year, ~city, ~charge, ~nitrogen_dioxide,
  2014, "City_A", TRUE, 110,
  2015, "City_A", TRUE, 109,
  2016, "City_A", TRUE, 108,
  2017, "City_A", TRUE, 107,
  2014, "City_B", FALSE, 150,
  2015, "City_B", FALSE, 148,
  2016, "City_B", TRUE, 135,
  2017, "City_B", TRUE, 133,
  2014, "City_C", FALSE, 90,
  2015, "City_C", FALSE, 89,
  2016, "City_C", FALSE, 88,
  2017, "City_C", FALSE, 87
)
```

How can I investigate whether the introduction of the congestion charge actually has an impact on the reduction of nitrogen dioxide?
To me, a regression doesn't really make sense with only one dummy variable as the independent variable.
Furthermore, it is a time series. How should I include the time in the model?
I would very much appreciate a suggestion for a statistical model. Also, a solution written in R would be very helpful.
If someone wants to have the original dataset, please add it as a comment.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How many cities and years ?

Comment: 22 cities and up to 15 years (with some gaps in the time series)